Music application - find albums w/o a tag for total number of tracks
I'm using macOS Sonoma 14.6.1 and Music 1.4.6
I like to curate my added music so each album has not only Track Numbers but also the Tag box for total number of tracks.
In the Track Column I want to see
1 of 4
2 of 4
3 of 4
4 of 4
or such. Not just the track number alone.
How can I find albums that do not have info in the total number of tracks tag. I don't know it that is the actual name for this tag.
I do not find such as a SmartPlaylist selection.
I check dougsscripts dot com to no avail. And done some searching.
thank you

I don't have a good way to search for tracks without totals for track numbers, but once you have found them...
I use Meta for all of my Music metadata editing needs, under Tools > Number Tracks you can add track and disc numbers along with their "totals."
It is not a free app, it is currently €25.00.

I exported a music library to an XML file (File > Library > Export Playlist),
and it has "Disc Number", "Disc Count", "Track Number" and "Track Count" keys in the XML.
The next thing is to find what attributes are exposed by the AppleScript dictionary for the Music.app.  Open the ScriptEditor then do (File > Open Dictionary...) and select the Music app.  After some scrolling around, I find the definition of a "track":
track n [inh. item] : playable audio source

and among its properties are:
time (text, r/o) : the length of the track in MM:SS format
track count (integer) : the total number of tracks on the source album
track number (integer) : the index of the track on the source album
unplayed (boolean) : is this track unplayed?

I'm not good enough with AppleScript to whip something up, but I think that will help. Have fun!
